# DATABASE_URL not set

Tags: sql, environment-variables

I am trying to load data on Jupyter notebook but got an error. I loaded SQL magic command %load_ext sql followed by %%sql
sqlite:///TMDB.db on a new line and I got the following error message:

```
Environment variable $DATABASE_URL not set, and no connect string given.
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

What could be the problem and how do I fix it in order to load and access this dataset?

I googled the error message and couldn't find a solution. I downloaded the dataset again and tried to load it again on Jupyter notebook but got the same error message